# Facebook Custom Ad Audience showing "Unknown" type when created via PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk) version 5.6.0 (latest) but any custom audience I create always shows "Unknown" underneath the audience name. I am trying to create a "Customer List" audience.

[image: Facebook Custom Audience created via API shows Unknown type]

I have confirmed that the API request sends over `subtype=CUSTOM` which is [mentioned here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api).

Here is the PHP:

```
$audience = new CustomAudience(null, $adAccount->id);

$audience->setData([
    CustomAudienceFields::NAME        => $name,
    CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE     => CustomAudienceSubtypes::CUSTOM,
    CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION => $description
]);

$audience->create();
```

Is this normal, or is my API request incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show "Unknown" until you add users into the audience.

Example:

```
$newAudience = $audience->create();

$emails = array(
    'test1@example.com',
    'test2@example.com',
    'test3@example.com',
);

$audience = new CustomAudience($newAudience->id);
$audience->addUsers($emails, CustomAudienceTypes::EMAIL);
```

Now you should see:

[image]